Телеграмм-бот на aiogram. Как скачать голосовое и передать его в функцию?
async def download_voice_as_ogg(voice):
    voice_file = await message.voice.get_file()
    ogg_filepath = os.path.join(AUDIOS_DIR, f"{generate_unique_name()}.ogg")
    await voice_file.download_to_drive(ogg_filepath)
    return ogg_filepath

Нашёл вот такую функцию, но ругается, что не существует функции get_file() для voice

Вы импортировали модуль? from aiogram.methods import GetFile

Документация по этом методу
